# Converting American Dates with time stamp

Tags: excel, date

I have an excel file with American dates and my system is set to use UK convention. Normally this is not a problem as you can just do the old text to columns so on and so forth. The issue I have with the current set of dates is the time stamp included prevents me from converting it to a British Date.

```
"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"
```

I've tried to convert this to date but that returns it as a date value which is wrong as my UK computer reads it incorrectly.

Does any one have any experience with this?

Comment: **Unclear** ............do you want the output to include the time or remove the time??

Comment: Well preferably yes (but would take without) but as it stands because of the time stamp I have no way of converting it to a UK date.

Comment: To further simplify this, what is the input and output that you want? For example:"I have dates formatted `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` and I need them formatted `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM`, then converted from Eastern Standard Time to Greenwich Mean Time."

Comment: Do you have the date values **(a)** stored as a date but formatted for US or **(b)** stored as a string? You can find out by looking at the number format that is used after pressing CTRL + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

This is clearly US format.  Select the cells and run this:

```
Sub DateTimeFixer()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comparing cell **C1** to the formula bar shows the format has been properly converted and the date has not been corrupted.

This can also be done manually through the menu system.

Comment: I just got to your last line Gary, and the whole time I am thinking why are you going the VBA route when you can simply cange the format of cell through the menu.  But alas you did say it.